# How to add a placeholder attribute in Django Form

Tags: python, django, forms, placeholder

I am having trouble in adding a placeholder attribute in my forms. I want to add a placeholder that will make my HTML look like:

```
<input type="text" name="sample" placeholder="sample">
```

Right now this is my codes look like.

This is my Models:

```
from django.db import models

class Sample(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=120)
```

and this is my Forms:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput
from .models import Sample

class SampleForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        INPUT_CLASS = 'form-control'

        model = Sample
        widgets = { 
            'name': TextInput(attrs={'class':INPUT_CLASS, 
                                     'placeholder':'Enter title here'}),
        }
```

Views

```
def update(request):

     sampleForm = SampleForm()

     return render(request, 'sample/profile.html', 'form':sampleForm)
```

In my forms when I include the placeholder attribute it is not working. What should be the best approach to let this work?

Comment: How are you rendering the form? Please post the relevant template code.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late, but I'll chip in anyway. I've been trying to do the same thing without having to redefine the widgets used in the form. Discovered that the following works:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # sets the placeholder key/value in the attrs for a widget
        # when the form is instantiated (so the widget already exists)
        self.fields['name_of_field'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'random placeholder'
```

EDIT: although I realize this doesn't answer your question of why your code doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

in form itself, this works for me always

```
class SampleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample

    name = forms.CharField(
        label='Name', 
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter title here'}
        )
    )
```

Comment: @solarissmoke I dont know yet