# Display form error in respective field form

Tags: django

Is possible to display form error in their respective field error form? And if not how can custom a field name on raise field error?

E.g. i have a signup/login system where i use `email` field as a ìdentifier. This becouse i use a custom signup/login system, with `BaseUserManager` and `AbstractBaseUser`, like:

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = u'Nome',
        max_length=33
    )
    #identifier
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name = u'Email',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    #....
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):   
    username = forms.EmailField(
        label="Email",
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}
    ))
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=False,
        max_length=50,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Senha'}
    ))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password']
```

The problem is, when `username`field form have an error, the message display : `username...error`, but i need show `Email...error`, preferably inside respective field. Even with `verbose_name = u'Email' in model.field, the error message display` username...errror...

So: 1- How can i display error inside respective form.field as `placeholder or value` and 2 - How customize the form.field.name.error when reise error?

Answer (score 0):

Add a validate fn in your form class for the validation as:

```py
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
  ...

  def validate(self, value):
        """Check if value consists only of valid emails."""
        # Use the parent's handling of required fields, etc.
        super().validate(value)
        for username in value:
            validate_username(username)
            validate_password(password)
```

Comment: Tks for atention, i dont understand where does it come from `validate_username() and validate_password()` methods?

Comment: you've to implement these methods inside the form yourself. return `true` if your condition matches or raise the Validation error else. ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Like how? Im django newb...

Comment: this tutorial might be hepful for you: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/form-validation-using-django

Comment: I just can see how, this solution, can override form.field.name from `username` to `email` , i try this solution, use `django.core.validators import validate_email`  once `username.field`  is the `email.field` identifier... so nothing change with this solution

Comment: And this tutorial, not applicable to my problem. The main problem is: I use custom signup/login system with AbstractBaseUser, the identifier field is `email`, but django see that as username, when that is defined in `models.py` as `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`

Comment: see here, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-form-validation-using-django/?ref=lbp, `clean` function inside form class may help, here you can add your own validations

Comment: I realy appreciatte your effort, but my problem is not valitadtion... look the answer more closely. Is not solve the problem

Comment: hmm, okay. In your meta fields, you're using `email` but the field registered is `username`. is that causing the problem? just asking.

Comment: Yes, now i dont remenber why exacly i needed to use `username` instead just `email`but i think when use `email` the other attribute cant be override...  i dont remenber why exacly

Comment: Yes, i test it now, if i change to `email`insted `username`, i cant overrride `placeholder`, this come blanck, no with `Email` in placeholder

Comment: sorry for unnecessary references ;)

Comment: hmm, maybe the placeholder are overwritten by the `Authentication Form`. you can try changing the placeholder in the init function like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626119/how-to-add-a-placeholder-attribute-in-django-form

Comment: Yes i try it but i dont find how is not work. Becouse that i change `email` to `username`and is works...